# Post Request with AFHttpRequestOperationManager not working

Tags: ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to post some JSON to my server, my code is below.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"john", @"name", @"xxxxx@gmail.com", @"email", @"xxxx", @"password", @"1", @"type", nil];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager setSecurityPolicy:policy];

[operationManager POST:@"posturl here" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}];
```

and the response is as follows:

```
2013-11-18 16:49:29.780 SwapOnceApiTester[12651:60b] Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415), got 1664256" UserInfo=0x1565a6c0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=xxxxxxx, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15656db0> { URL: xxxxxxxxx } { status code: 415, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=604800";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 18 Nov 2013 11:49:28 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 25 Nov 2013 11:49:28 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415), got 1664256}
```

I dont know what the problem is with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve my problem, my server was not configured to accept the charset utf8 with application/json so i just removed the charset utf for ajson serializer in Afnetworking 2.0 and now it is working correclty.

Comment: Could you be more specific - where did you remove and what?

Answer (score 29):

You need to set your request and response serializers to handle JSON using `AFJSONRequestSerializer` and `AFJSONResponseSerializer` before executing your request. Using an NSDictionary literal for your parameters helps code clarity as well:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager setSecurityPolicy:policy];
operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operationManager POST:@"posturl here" 
            parameters: @{@"name":  @"john",
                        @"email":   @"xxxxx@gmail.com",
                        @"password: @"xxxxx",
                        @"type":    @"1"}
               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                   NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
               } 
               failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
               }
];
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying, i have tried this as well but the result is same, this is the response i am getting now { status code: 415, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=604800";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 20 Nov 2013 06:52:24 GMT";
    Expires = "Wed, 27 Nov 2013 06:52:24 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415), got 0}  , i dont know why the content-length is zero.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The parameter passed to server is empty.