# how to POST json data and response json in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, json-rpc

I use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager for query data from service, but i want set data for POST json data parameters to service.

Thank you for answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047090/post-request-with-afhttprequestoperationmanager-not-working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, this problem solved.

Example code :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *requestHTTP = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:my_url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];

[requestHTTP setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[requestHTTP setValue:AUTHORIZATION_VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[requestHTTP setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestHTTP setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requestHTTP];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}];

[op start];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[operationManager POST:@"yourUrl" parameters:yourParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```