# Firebase send push notification from devices (IOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In ios I am using Firebase database and FCM. I have to send push notification from devices to devices by devices token. I have FCM API "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" This is post method and add parameter 
Like :

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

but when I try to call this API this is alway return me an error , and the same API calling from android devices this is working in android, not in ios Here is my code and error, please give me the solution

```
-(void)sendPush
{



     NSDictionary *noti = @{@"body": @"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message", @"title": @"high"};
    NSDictionary *data = @{@"text": @"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message", @"title": @"high"};
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"to": @"dbpuoXnzY3o:APA91bH3AE_XCbsLpOXycNULcSh1GHzohEFdopmzkY_n8bm78E9_5fHyY3PLCwi5HtTLU_IoOwfdbDc5qCbyzc6tD9Ahg0EviCfbAmhftmMsPqfi0WC...",@"notification":noti,@"data":data};
    NSLog(@"%@",params);

    [NetworkManager postNotification:params getUrl:@"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" success:^(id response) {
         NSLog(@"%@",response);



    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];

}
```

in nslog this looks like this

```
{
    data =     {
        text = "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message";
        title = high;
    };
    notification =     {
        body = "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message";
        title = high;
    };
    to = "dbpuoXnzY3o:APA91bH3AE_XCbsLpOXycNULcSh1GHzohEFdopmzkY_n8bm78E9_5fHyY3PLCwi5HtTLU_IoOwfdbDc5qCbyzc6tD9Ahg0EviCfbAmhftmMsPqfi0WC...";
}
```

Afnetworking calling function

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];


    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                                  serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
   // [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"AIzaSyADxgFPrxx....." forHTTPHeaderField:@"key"];

   // NSLog(@"Token==%@",[GeneralSetting sharedInstance].token_number);
    [manager POST:URL parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:appDelegate.window animated:YES];
        success(responseObject);

        ////NSLog(@"success!");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        failure(error);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:appDelegate.window animated:YES];
      NSLog(@"error: %@", error.description);

        // [self alert:@"" title:@""];
    }];
```

ERROR is

```
error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17024a1d0 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17402fa40> { URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 259;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 04 Jul 2017 10:17:43 GMT";
    Expires = "Tue, 04 Jul 2017 10:17:43 GMT";
    Server = GSE;
    "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"39,38,37,36,35\"";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} },
```

Please help me , Please give me solution

I have tried from postmen this is working from postmen

[image]

same data i am sending from code this is not working may be problem is sending dictionary 
I am using this code

```
NSDictionary *noti = @{@"body": @"Hello", @"title": @"This is test message"};

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"to": [GeneralSetting sharedInstance].token_number,@"notification":noti};
    NSLog(@"%@",params);
```

AND

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"key=AIzaSy.....tBxdYAIRp2KBG0NoS8dOqgy4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

The Response is

```
{
    notification =     {
        body = Hello;
        title = "This is test message";
    };
    to = "dQgCDOK3sec:APA91zFbkqkgyTNrsYsEmUJwpCtMs1VAmXF9DpF_zQfBYui3UjCA9nYtS_TK549RPnlWEfe-jSvD9MMc3lTFNsGJlyIOqNm84s8GoW1LfTGG0geuWEclb";
}

 Request failed: bad request (400)
```

Comment: Did you check with postman? Is that working API?

Comment: I dont know postman, I have to try send push from FCM control and devices get push from devices token

Comment: Content type required `acceptableContentTypes = application/json`. Which you mention in the top. Your Error shows you just set content type `"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";`

Comment: I have update my question , I have using Postman and this is working , postman sending push , but how can i do from code after some correction in code i am getting bad request error .

Comment: Did you compare your POSTMAN content-type and your response? Also check others too.

Comment: can you upload your final code which is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1) Allow your app to accept the `text/html` data with:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
// OR
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

2) Or better, change your data type so it is `application/json` as **@user3589771** mentioned.

Make sure `AFHTTPSessionManager` is correctly formatting the JSON with `AFJSONRequestSerializer`

References: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082601/4221083)

Answer (score 0):

just follow this - simple post method

**Push notification using objective c**

```
    NSDictionary *noti= @{@
        "body" : @"This is an FCM notification message with device token !",
        @"title" : @"FCM Message",
    };
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"to": @"devicetoken",@"notification":noti};
        NSLog(@"%@",params);

    NSError *error;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"]];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"key=AAAAz_****" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPBody: postData];


    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        if(error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"error is comming %@", error);
        }
        NSHTTPURLResponse *asHTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                            NSLog(@"The response is: %@", asHTTPResponse);

    }] resume];
```